# Sequelize: How to order results by CHAR LENGTH?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Is there a way to order my results by the length (characters) of a column in sequelise ?

For example if I search for "lor" I would like to get result below:

```
results
________________
lor
lorem
lorem ip
lorem ips
lorem ipsum
```

Any suggestions gratefully received

Comment: In MySQL you can use the `LIKE` clause to find matches in a column

Comment: @Noob i'm using sequelise orm and It's about ordering not finding

Comment: You can order on length in MySQL with these query for example `ORDER BY LENGTH(description) DESC;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ORDER`, e.g.:

```
order: [
    [sequelize.fn('length', sequelize.col('column_name')), 'DESC']
 ]
```